# What is the easiest way for grepping the 'man grep' for flags

Tags: unix, grep, flags, manpage

I do use grep a lot, but I would love to improve a bit.

Regarding the question. I wanted to narrow the `man` entry to find the explanation of what the `-v` in `grep -v 'pattern' filename` stood for, mainly this:

```
 -v, --invert-match
         Selected lines are those not matching any of the specified patterns.
```

Thus, to find the next five lines after the line which contains `-v` I tried:

`man grep | grep -A 5 -v`

and

`man grep | grep -A 5 '-v'`

but they return:

```
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

This confuses me since:

`man grep | grep -A 5 'Selected'`

and

`man grep | grep -A 5 Selected`

do work.

What is wrong in my approach? Is there any easier way to achieve what I need?

Comment: What about browsing through it by using `/` followed by the term you are looking for?

Comment: I agree with above form of searching, however, your issue is that your search item starts with a hyphen, hence grep thinks it is another option.  Like many commands, you can use 2 hyphens (--) prior to the regex and this tells commands to treat what comes next as text.  You could also simply escape the hyphen (\-)

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://superuser.com OR http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: `man grep | grep -A 5 '^[[:space:]]*-v'` or perhaps `man grep | sed -n '/^[[:space:]]*-v/,/^$/{/^$/d;p}'`?

Comment: Whether  you type `grep -A 5 -v` or `grep -A 5 '-v'`, grep sees exactly the same 3 arguments.  You could get the same results with `gr'e'p "-A" '5' -"v"`.  In each case `grep` sees the strings `-A`, `5`, and `-v`.

Comment: I wrote a reply, but I think @grail has the right idea.  Use the `--` flag to tell grep to no longer parse data after the `--` as flags to grep.  As an aside, it's also how to remove a file named `-f`.  Or list it "long":  `ls -- -f` or `rm -- -f` for example.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to parse the `Info` documents for the command directly.  If you run `info grep` (or other command) you will often find much more detailed and better-structured documentation, which will let you pin-point just the section you need.

Here's a function that will print out the relevant `Info` section for an option/variable/etc:

```
info_search() {
   info --subnodes "$1" -o -  2>&- \
   | awk -v RS='' "/(^|\n)(‘|'|\`)$2((,|\[| ).*)?(’|')\n/"
}
```

This should work on Linux/macOS/BSD.  Output is like:

```
$ info_search grep -v
‘-v’
‘--invert-match’
     Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (‘-v’
     is specified by POSIX.)
```

```
$ info_search gawk RS
'RS == "\n"'
     Records are separated by the newline character ('\n').  In effect,
     every line in the data file is a separate record, including blank
...
```

```
$ info_search bash -i
`-i'
     Force the shell to run interactively.  Interactive shells are
...
```